# what is the maximum number of fields per document in elasticsearch when considering performance while indexing?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using elasticsearch for displaying products in my app feed, I am currently having 8 fields for scoring the documents of type product.

I want to have multiple scores (1000-2000) for a single document, which is equivalent to 2000 fields per document in ES. Is this okay? will it affect performance when indexing those products?

mapping

```
{"activity_objects":
{"mappings":
    {"activity_object":
        {"properties":
            {
            "name":{"type":"String"},
            ...
            "category_ids":{"type":"long"},
            "sorting_score_a":{"type":"long"},
            "sorting_score_b":{"type":"long"},
            "sorting_score_c":{"type":"long"},
            "sorting_score_d":{"type":"long"},

            ....
            }       
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now there is only 4 sorting scores, I want to increase the count of sorting scores, approximately the number of scores will be in the range of 1000-2000.

Comment: can you share your rough mappings/schema and what kind of relationship they share

Comment: @user3775217 have updated the mapping, please take a look at it